# Implementing Naive Bayes using SAS Enterprise Miner 7.1

Tags: sas, enterprise

I have been trying to implement the Naive Bayes and OneR classification algorithm using SAS Enterprise Miner 7.1.

The problem is I have not been able to find a Node that I can drag onto the diagram and do that. Is there any way to implement these algorithms directly in SAS without having to write additional SAS Script?

Comment: Please provide more information to base an answer on.

Comment: I need to know if there is a node that I can drag onto my diagram in SAS Enterprise Miner in order to perform the Naive Bayes and OneR classification algorithm. Can you tell me if your need any other specific information?

Comment: Could someone please help me with the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: http://listserv.uga.edu/cgi-bin/wa?A2=ind1202c&L=sas-l&D=0&P=2796

I don't think this is possible using a native node.  The above link suggests that Rick Wicklin did write something that might help here, but it's beyond my google-fu.  You might re-ask this question on the SAS-L mailing list (email to sas-l@listserv.uga.edu or find the Google Group).

Comment: Thank you Joe I will look into doing that.